# Lookup function on nested locals variable

Tags: terraform

Using the lookup function, how could I lookup the value of c?

```
lookup({a="ay", b={c="ce"}}, "c", "what?")
"what?"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to produce the value `"what?"` if *either* `b` or `b.c` are absent from the data structure then you can achieve that concisely using [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html):

```
> try({ a = "ay", b = { c = "ce" } }.b.c, "what?")
"ce"
> try({ a = "ay", b = {} }.b.c, "what?")
"what?"
> try({ a = "ay" }.b.c, "what?")
"what?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
locals {
  # NOTE:     lookup(map, key, default)
  value_out = lookup({a="ay", b={c="ce"}}, "b", "what?")
  value_out_c = local.value_out.c
}

output "value_returned_c" {
  value = local.value_out_c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with terraform version v1.0.0. Not sure whether it solves your problem?

```
lookup(lookup({a="ay", b={c="ce"}}, "b", "what?"),"c", "what")
```